# テラフォームのバージョンの見方がわかりません

Tags: terraform

テラフォームのバージョンの見方がよくわかりません。

`cd /usr/local/Cellar/tfenv/3.0.0/versions`に今ローカルに入っているバージョンを確認でき、

`3.0.0/versions`の内容が `1.3.2`となっております。

テラフォームのバージョンはこの`3.0.0`のことと思っておりました。

２週類の数字`3.0.0/versions`と`1.3.2`の違いは何かご教授願います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

パスに `tfenv/` が含まれているので、Terraform の複数バージョンを管理できる [tfenv](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv) を使用しているのが混乱の元じゃないでしょうか。

`Cellar/tfenv/3.0.0` に関してはあくまで tfenv のバージョン、(設定されている) Terraform 自体のバージョンは以下のコマンドで確認してみてください。

```
$ terraform --version
```

Comment: わかりやすい回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: https://public-constructor.com/manage-terraform-versions-with-tfenv/